# If $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on a set $X$, then there exists an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

**Definition**:

> A maximal element in the partially ordered set (for the inclusion
>   relation) of all filters on a set $X$ is called an ultrafilter on $X$

**Theorem:**

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on a set $X$, then there exists an
>   ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq
>  \mathcal{U}$

**Proof my book provides**:

> Consider the set $\mathcal{X} := \{\mathcal{G} \mid
> \mathcal{G}\mathrm{\ filter}, \mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}\}$.
>   Then $(\mathcal{X}, \subseteq)$ is a poset and it is inductive
>   ordened. Hence, the existence of the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ follows
>   by Zorn's lemma. $\square$

**My questions**:

> 1) I already proved that the set of all filters on $X$ is partially
>   ordered. Does this imply that the poset ($\mathcal{X}, \subseteq)$ is
>   inductive ordened as well? I think not, but my book claims it does.
>
> 2) The proof in my book gives a maximal element of the set
>   $\mathcal{X}$, which is a subset of the set of all filters. Hence, is
>   the maximal element found by Zorn's lemma also a maximal element in
>   the set of all filters on $X$? This should be true (but I can't prove
>   it), in order for $\mathcal{U}$ (that is found in the proof) to be an
>   ultrafilter by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the definition of inductive order in that book, but in [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InductiveSet.html) one possibility is a partially ordered set in which every totally ordered subset has an upper bound.

This is the case of $(\mathcal X,\subseteq)$ because if $(\mathcal G_i)_{i \in I}$ is a chain of filters containing $\mathcal F$, then $\mathcal G=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal G_i$ is an upper bound of that chain.
So you are in conditions of applying Zorn's Lemma, and conclude that $(\mathcal X,\subseteq)$ has a maximal element which is, therefore, an ultrafilter.

Comment: Yes, it is that definition. But why is a maximal element of $(\mathcal{X}, \subseteq)$ an ultrafilter? An ultrafilter must be a maximal element of the set of all filters.

Comment: @Math_QED A maximal filter among those that contain $F$ is a maximal filter overall.

Comment: Yes, ok. I see it. And for the second question, is the set inductive ordened because the set of all filters on $X$ is inductive ordened? I can't see how this would follow, but I can see it is true by doing the same proof.

Comment: @Math_QED if $\mathcal H$ is **a** maximal element (it can have more than one) then the implication you're asking follows from $\mathcal H$ being maximal. All elements is $\mathcal X$ contain $\mathcal F$.

Comment: @Math_QED It is obvious that a maximal element in $\mathcal X$ is maximal in the set of all filters. For if $H$ is maximal in $\mathcal X$, and $H \subseteq K$, where $K$ is another filter, then $F \subseteq K$ (because $F \subseteq H$) and thus $K \in \mathcal X$, yielding $K=H$ because $H$ is maximal in $\mathcal X$.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant the first question.

Comment: @Math_QED That's what I answer in the third line: if you have a chain in that set, the union is also there, and it is an upper bound of the chain.